# Android ICS 4.0.3 Local ajax doesn't work

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-webview

I have an android app with Webview and uses JQuery in the webview
The JS in the webview fetches a local file to load templates
using the following code:

```
$.get("file:///android_asset/www/templates.html",function(data){
     $("#templates").html(data);
});
```

This code never works and I always get unknown chromium error: -6

This error happens on ICS 4.X and works normally in Froyo, Gingerbread, and Honeycomb

I also tried this code:

```
$.ajax({
         url : "file:///android_asset/www/",
         type:"get",
         data : null, 
         cache:false,
         success:function(data){
               activity.doLog("Got it to work"); // This refers to Log.d in activity
                return false;
         },
         error:function(xhr,msg,thrown){
               activity.doLog("Didn't get it '"+msg.replace("\n"," --- "));
               // Logged error here is    'error 
               // Which is meaningless message
           return false;
         }
```

});

**Update:**

I found a solution/workaround for this problem (that doesn't make sense at all)
The solution is simply: the locally loaded file must not contain single quotes, I don't know why but changing all the single quotes to double quotes solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution/workaround for this problem (that doesn't make sense at all) The solution is simply: the locally loaded file must not contain single quotes, I don't know why but changing all the single quotes to double quotes solved the problem.

- Also change cache: false to cache: true or just remove it