# jquery load local files

Tags: jquery, html, xss

i have this Fiddle Here  http://jsfiddle.net/kd6Y4/1/

which is getting div from a different page on same site and display it the problem is its working perfectly online like this direct link http://fiddle.jshell.net/kd6Y4/1/show/ search for hand or and in both

but its not working offline due to cross site scripting  restriction please help make it work offline as i need to use this offline in a android environment and also in offline browsers

```
  $("#searchForm").submit(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
var results = $("#resultContainer");
var text = $("#search").val();
results.empty();
$.get("url here", function (data) {
var els = $(data).find("div:contains(" + text + ")").appendTo(results);
els.find('a').attr('href', function (_, href) {
    return 'url here/#' + $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
})
});
 });
```

[this error is coming how to resolve]

XML Http request cannot load file no "access control allow origin" header is present on the requested resource origin stuff is therefore not allowed access

Comment: if you are using local file system url then you need to keep the resources in the same directory else same origin policy will not allow you to access those resources

Comment: i have Kept both files in same directory its not working yet

Comment: sorry for so many questions am new to jquery

Comment: which is the browser used

Comment: chrome i am getting proper results when browser security is disabled  is there any way to get the same result while using it offline ?

Comment: i have to use this in android webview

Comment: try https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw11nR4GFSJ8aEh0MXU1Y1JuRnM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: tried this its not working i used exactly same code

Comment: which is the browser used and OS

Comment: windows 8 and chrome browser issue occuring here is of cross site scripting its taking local files as different url it works perfectly when browser security is turned off

Comment: which option did you turn off

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --disable-web-security  in cmd after closing chrome  how can i do this with android webview app

Comment: for me it is working without any change.. in windows 7 & chrome latest

Comment: if you have firefox try https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw11nR4GFSJ8MTZyZVVzTWg0dWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: yes but its not working in android webview cross site scripting is the issue

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648616/webview-javascript-cross-domain-from-a-local-html-file

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098437/android-ics-4-0-3-local-ajax-doesnt-work

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so that you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function(){
    $("#searchForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var results = $("#resultContainer");
        var text = $("#search").val();
        results.empty();
        $.get("test2.html", function (data) {
            var els = $(data).find("div:contains(" + text + ")").appendTo(results);
            els.find('a').contents().unwrap();
            els.wrap(function(){
                return $('<a/>', {
                    href: 'test2.html#' +this.id
                })
            })
        }, 'html').fail(function(){
            console.log('arge', arguments)
        });
    });
})
```

and to make local files work follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648616/webview-javascript-cross-domain-from-a-local-html-file)